# How to convert a nested dictionary to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I've been struggling with this for a while. How to convert a dictionary each element of which looks like this

```
{'00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF': {1: (48947218088,),
      2: (48947218089,),
      3: (48947218088, 48947218089)}}
```

into a dataframe that will look like this?

| id | combination_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF | 1 | 48947218088 |
| 00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF | 2 | 48947218089 |
| 00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF | 3 | 48947218088 |
| 00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF | 3 | 48947218089 |

Comment: What did you try so far? Share your code please

Comment: Duplicates without accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53367498/12846804. Different answers. Maybe review those into one post

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and chain [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF': {1: (48947218088,),
      2: (48947218089,),
      3: (48947218088, 48947218089)}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.unstack().explode().reset_index(drop=False)
df.columns = ['id','combination_id', 'value']
print(df)

                id  combination_id        value
0  00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF               1  48947218088
1  00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF               2  48947218089
2  00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF               3  48947218088
3  00OZ2dKSA5jUfvF               3  48947218089
```